# Unable to autowire field in stage class when Jgiven classrule and method rule are using

Tags: junit5, jgiven

I am writing a Jgiven test scenario.

I have created all the three stage classes.

With SpringScenarioTest extending, everything is working fine.

I am using Jgiven class rules and method rules. When using Jgiven class rule, I am unable to autowire a field in stage class. I have a base class which I am extending with my Jgiven test class. My Base class is annotated with @Springboottest and @enableJgiven. All my scenario stages are included in the Jgiven test with annotation @ScenarioStage.

Could you please help me how to autowire a field when using Junit class rules?